# Which is better way between develop new system and modify open source Ad Classified?

Tags: php, ads

I take few days to look around internet to find out best open source Ad Classified. I would build it with PHP.

I found few Ad Classified which is good such as OSClass, and Open Classified. But I may need to modified to what I needed.

I am stuck in idea to choose which is the best way to go. Should I build a new system or should I take and modified.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get off the ground I recommend going with modifying an open source solution.

On one hand, if you build a brand new system then you'll most likely encounter all of the same pitfalls and bugs that the other package developers have already worked through.  However, you are also inheriting all of the bugs and problems that someone else has written.  Read through the reviews for the package to see if there's any horrible security problems or bugs.

If you find a package that does ALMOST everything you want then definitely modify it to your needs.  It really comes down to your skill level and comfort with tackling the job of writing your own package.  To start I would make a list of everything you want to offer and compare it with what's out there.  Writing a package from scratch sounds easy but it can quickly turn into a giant endeavor.

hth